# Redirect subdomain to url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect 123.mydomain.com to http://mydomain.com/xyz. I thought I could try using an alias in my DNS zone file but apparently that is not the way to go about. Must I use a redirect in htaccess and if so how would this be done?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1/xyx%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` it would be something like::

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/xyz/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```